# No files are being checked out on a CVS checkout

Tags: file, cvs, vcs-checkout

I installed a CVS server today. I installed cvs server using sudo apt-get install cvsd. Now the folder where everything is stored is /var/lib/cvsd/cvsrepo/test. Folder test contains a dummy text file by the name check.txt, which would prove everything works fine.

My CVSROOT on the client machine is ":pserver: username@localhost:/cvsrepo". When I do a cvs login, it asks me for a password, and authenticates me well. Then I do a cvs checkout, "cvs checkout test". Test folder is the module, while cvsrepo is the repository. When I download test first I get the message "cvs checkout: Updating testFolder" and then a folder by the name test is created, but it does not have the dummy file, check.txt in the client machine. A checkout only is creating a folder CVS which contains the Entries, Repository, and Root folders? Why isn't the text file being downloaded?

Comment: Did you add the file using `cvs import` or `cvs add` + `cvs commit`?

Comment: no I just created it directly!!

Comment: I just went into the repository and created a folder and then the file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be saying that you have a file `/var/lib/cvsd/cvsrepo/test/check.txt`. If so, this is not a valid part of your repository. A file that appears as `test/check.txt` in a checkout would be `text/check.txt,v` in the repository, and its contents would be a CVS/RCS file with revision history.

You can create directories in a CVS repository directly with `mkdir`, though it's not recommended. You can't create files that way, you have to check out a directory, create a file in the directory and commit the file.